# なぜRailsのモジュールでは"able"をサフィックスとして付けるのでしょうか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails を使っていて、モジュール名の末尾に `able` というサフィックスを見かけることがあります。どのような場合に、なぜこのサフィックスを付けるのでしょうか。

[Put chubby models on a diet with concerns – Signal v. Noise](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns)

例えば上記のサイトでは次のようなコードが書かれています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スタックオーバーフローにようこそ！ココは日本語版のサイトです。質問は日本語に翻訳して掲載してください。そうすれば回答を得られると思います。

Comment: Japanese OK とも書かれていたので日本語話者と判断し、本文を日本語に訳しました。もし意図せぬ内容になっていましたらご指摘いただくか、お手数ですがご自身で[edit]していただければと思います。

Answer (score 5):

RailsのConcernで使われるモジュール名はたしかに xxx-able となっているものが多いです。
実際僕もよく xxx-able という名前のモジュールを作ります。

が、これはあくまで慣習であり、規約ではありません。
なので、xxx-able以外のモジュール名にしても全く問題ありません。

一般論として、クラス名/モジュール名やメソッド名には「わかりやすい名前」を付けるのが原則です。
なので、たとえば「includeすると **タグが使える** ようになるモジュール」であれば、「タグが使える = Tag + able = Taggable」という名前を付けるとわかりやすい、ということになります。
ですが、絶対ではないので、Taggableよりも適切な名前があると考えるのであれば、別の名前を付けるのもアリです。

とはいえ、「Concernであればxxx-ableにする」というのがRailsの世界では「暗黙の了解」になっているので（個人的な観測範囲では）、よっぽど不自然な名前や意味がわからない名前にならない限り、xxx-ableにした方が他のRailsプログラマにとってもわかりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

モジュール名の末尾に"-able"を付ける理由は、そのモジュールがMixinしたクラスに機能を追加するからだと私は考えています。

Railsのconcernsディレクトリには、関心事を分離するために独立した機能を定義したモジュールが配置されます。例にあるようなTaggableモジュールも、独立した機能を定義したモジュールの1つです。
そのため、命名規則として"-able"をモジュール名の末尾に付けると感じられたのだと思います。

よって、そのモジュールがMixinしたクラスに機能を追加する場合は、名前の末尾に"-able"を付けると分かりやすいモジュール名になると思います。